# Get the OS of an instance from an AMI

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, boto

Is it possible to get the OS type from an AWS AMI via Boto?

ie. MSWinSQLWeb, RHEL, SLES, LINUX/UNIX, etc....?

-RBL

Answer (score 1):

Not exactly sure what you are trying to achieve, but this may be it:

```
boto.ec2.get_only_instances()
```

The returned `Instance` objects will have some informative properties, like:

- **platform** – Platform of the instance (e.g. Windows)
- **kernel** – The kernel associated with the instance.
- **architecture** – The architecture of the image (i386|x86_64).
- **product_codes** – A list of product codes associated with this instance.

Comment: Platform and Kernel are quite often 'None' and product_codes is quite often '[ ]'. I think information needs to be retrieved from the AMI